# C# overriding with child class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, overloading

Lately I've stuck with some project. What I want to do?
I have some number of classes. Let's say something like that:

```c#
public class ActionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Creature actor;
}

public class LocationEventArgs : ActionEventArgs
{
    public Location loc;
}

public class Action
{
    public virtual void Do(object sender, ActionEventArgs e)
    {
        //... do something with it;
    }
}

public class LocationAction : Action
{
    public override void Do(object sender, LocationEventArgs e) // error, signatures differs
    {
        //... do something with it;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public Action a { get; protected set; }

    public void InitAction()
    {
        a = new LocationAction();
    }

    public void DoAction(Creature actor, Location location)
    {
        a.Do(this, new LocationEventArgs() { actor = actor, loc = location });
    }
}
```

Well, it didn't work because of different methods signatures. Ok.
Of course, I can use something like class checks like:

```c#
public class LocationAction : Action
{
    public override void Do(Action sender, ActionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e is LocationEventArgs) throw new ArgumentException("e must be LocationEventArgs");
        //... do something with it;
    }
}
```

But I don't really like it, because it's only runtime thing. So, the question is: how to do this properly? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics):

```cs
public class Action<TArg> where TArg : ActionEventArgs
{
    public virtual void Do(object sender, TArg e)
    {
        // can access 'e.actor'
    }
}

public class LocationAction : Action<LocationEventArgs>
{
    public override void Do(object sender, LocationEventArgs e)
    {
        // can access 'e.actor' and 'e.loc'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way. Overriding won't solve this problem; overloading might, but then the classes get messy as you add more types. Generics are the optimal solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are willing to do goes against the principle itself. You can't override and change the parameters. maybe add a

> public override void Do(object sender, LocationEventArgs e) // error,
> signatures differs
> {
> //... do something with it;
> }

in your action class ?